# PHP make class propery inheritable

Tags: php, class, inheritance, properties

i have 2 classes A and B that extends A. A has a public property and i want that on the instances of B that property can't be accessible. I try to explain better:

```
class A
{
    public $prop;
}
class B extends A
{
    ...
}
$instance=new B;
$instance->prop; //This must throw an error like "Undefined property prop"
```

I tried with the `final` keyword but it's only available for methods not for properties. I tried also by setting the same property as `private` on B but PHP does not allow to change the access level from public to private or protected.

Maybe there's a simple solution to this problem but i can't find it so do you know a way to do this?

Comment: Are you extending someone else's class? Why can you not fix the problem at its origin?

Comment: Why do you want to declare a property as public (i.e. the widest visibility possible) and then deny its access to descendant classes?

Comment: I don't want to make private a public property i want that B does not inherit it. I've changed the access level only to find a good solution but it doesn't work

Comment: Well, I hate to say it, but I think you're doing it wrong.  Inheritance is when you want to use ALL of the underlying parent class inside the child.  If you don't, then either your archetecture is messed up (that the child really shouldn't extend the parent), or your problem is better solved using another pattern (like [composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition))...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [magic methods](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php)

```
class A {
    protected $_prop;
    public function __get($key) {   
        if ($key=='prop') {
            return $this->_prop;
        }
    }

    public function __set($key, $value) {
        if ($key=='prop') {
            return $this->_prop = $value;
        }
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public function __get($key) {
    }

    public function __set($key, $value) {
    }

    // how you can use it
    public function foo() {
        echo $this->_prop;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply change `public $prop;` to `private $prop;` by making $prop `public` you are making it accessible by every possible way, but making it `private` will make it accessible within a class only

Comment: I was looking for a way to preserve the property on the base class, but maybe there's no other way.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm. Tricky!

The only idea that comes to mind is making `$prop` private from the start, and using [magic getter and setter functions](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php) to control access. You'd have to store the access information in a separate array and then either return the correct value, or throw a fatal error in the getter function.